# How to add colorbar to existing axis handle?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

This way is easy and works:

```
plt.imshow(im)
plt.colorbar()
```

But when it's like this:

```
f,ax = plt.subplots(3,1)
ax[2].imshow(im)
```

How do I get the colorbar on that axis? I don't need anything fancy, just the defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the respective image and axes handles into [`fig.colorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar):

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1)

im2 = axs[2].imshow(im)
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=axs[2])
```